Ускорение работы qmake для генерации makefile
Интересует, как можно ускорить генерацию makefile при помощи qmake. Qmake выполняется в один поток, и генерация мейкфайлов занимает существенно больше времени, чем их последующая сборка с помощью make. Есть ли в принципе возможность такого ускорения, помимо замены процессора на более мощный и замены HDD на SSD? Возможно есть какой-то вариант распараллеливания однопоточного приложения?

qmake должен запускаться только при изменении структуры проекта. Обычные изменения файлах требуют только вызова make. Или у вас не так?

@StanislavVolodarskiy У меня так. Но когда выполняется полная пересборка проекта с нуля, хочется ее как-то ускорить. Qmake генерит мейкфайлы за 40 секунд, а make их потом собирает за 5.

Может это поможет? https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-37252

@StanislavVolodarskiy Спасибо, попробую.
